# How to build a custom column formula in Power query that will retrieve Image and load it to Excel to display that image from the specified column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

So I'm trying build this custom column formula that will return the image from the specified column URL and then load it to Excel. But somehow it's not working.

Basically I want the query to work exactly like '=Image()' function in excel that retrieves images from the URL. Can anyone help me with this formula/query?

Here are the things that I have done so far

I have added a custom column formula
[image]

After Expanded Image It's showing a error
[image]

After loading the query It's showing this
[image]

Actual result that I want
[image]

Answer (score 2):

To resolve your error, make sure ignore privacy is checked in your power query settings. There are 2 options (Global and Current Workbook) so change both to be sure.  They should both be set to "Always ignore".

[image]

However, this still won't bring in binary image data from a url and I'm not sure there is a way to do so. If you already have the urls of the images, why don't you just paste those directly into Excel?

Comment: the only thing I've ever seen is https://www.kasperonbi.com/loading-an-image-into-the-model-using-power-query/

Comment: It's now working, but It's showing in Binary format. I can do it in excel manually but I wanted to automate it. So, that It's always there when ever I update the data. Can you  suggest any other method to automate this?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Maybe the link from @horseyride may help.